# Determine if SDF database is encrypted

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce

Is there any way to determine, before connecting and having an exception thrown, if an SQL Compact Edition SDF has password encryption?

After selecting the file in an **Open File Dialog**, I want to check if there is a password encrypting the SDF and prompt for the password.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to determine if any file is either encrypted or compressed is to try and compress it again. Obviously SQLCE does not support compression, so if the SDF **cant** compress, it is encrypted.